# curl: (6) Could not resolve host

Tags: php, macos, curl, instagram, instagram-api

I am trying to get the Instagram api authorization token. I made commands exactly as the one indicated on https://www.instagram.com/developer/authentication/

```
curl -F 'client_id=CLIENT_ID' \
-F 'client_secret=CLIENT_SECRET' \
-F 'grant_type=authorization_code' \
-F 'redirect_uri=AUTHORIZATION_REDIRECT_URI' \
-F 'code=CODE' \
https://api.instagram.com/oauth/access_token
```

However, the terminal returns with an error

```
    curl: (6) Could not resolve host: client_secret=CLIENT_SECRET
    curl: (6) Could not resolve host: grant_type=authorization_code-F
    curl: (6) Could not resolve host: redirect_uri=https
    curl: (6) Could not resolve host: code=CODE
```

Does anyone know why this happens? I'm using OSX

Answer (score 2):

You should not hit return between each line. Copy and paste the whole chunk and it should work.

Comment: this is the correct answer